# Unable to run test script using Gecko driver(0.19.1); latest Selenium jars(3.7.1) and FF(57.0)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

Trying to run my script in Mozilla Firefox using Gecko driver(0.19.1); latest Selenium jars(3.7.1) and FF(57.0);

browser launches but URL is not running in browser; getting screen as shown below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPgdM.png)

This welcome page appears always and in Console it displays logs as:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: Malformed URL: baseURL is not a valid URL.
Build info: version: '3.7.1', revision: '8a0099a', time: '2017-11-06T21:07:31.527Z'
System info: host: 'BIZ4SOL-8', ip: '192.168.1.67', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_31'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 56.0, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:headless: false, moz:processID: 6688, moz:profile: C:\Users\pratik\AppData\Loc..., pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, platformVersion: 6.1, rotatable: false, specificationLevel: 0, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}}
Session ID: 7af514e7-7f11-44cb-a15d-e50aaf431874
```

Comment: It's not an issue with geckodriver. You are providing `Malformed URL: baseURL is not a valid URL`. What URL are you trying to open?

Answer (score 0):

1. Try this: write for Your browser FirefoxDriver.SystemProperty.DRIVER_USE_MARIONETTE,"true" 
   e.g.:

   ```
   FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
   System.setProperty ("webdriver.gecko.driver", "path_to_driver/geckodriver.exe");
   System.setProperty(FirefoxDriver.SystemProperty.DRIVER_USE_MARIONETTE,"true");
   driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
   ```

2.Are You using driver.get("url"); correct?